# How to remove space between h2 and paragraph

Tags: blank-line

I want to remove the blank line between my h2 and p elements that is in an article tag (Why use article? MY instructor asked that we use 5 new html5 elements in our project.) I have tried:

```
#prime h2 {
     margin-top:0em; 
}

#prime p  {
         margin-bottom:0em;
}
```

This moved my h2 all the way over to the right and into 2 lines. . 
Then I tried stack/overflow suggestion from Josmh answered Oct 13 '11 at 19:16:

```
 #prime h2,p{
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #prime h2,p {
        display: inline;
    }
```

This moved my nav bar to the same line as the h2, Welcome to Parties by Carol.

Is the code not working because I am using article? My code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Parties by Carol</title>
<script src="SpryAssets/SpryMenuBar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarHorizontal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <header id="hdr">
    <h3>throw a ball</h3>
    <h2>throw a line</h2>
    <h1>Throw a Party!</h1>
    <div id="party"><img src="images/balloons2.jpg" width="125" height="125" alt="A Party"/></div>
    <p>Parties by Carol</p>
    <ul id="MenuBar1" class="MenuBarHorizontal">
      <li><a href="Final-1.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a class="MenuBarItemSubmenu" href="#">Types of       Parties</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Quinceneras/Sweet 16</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Bar/Bat Mitzvahs</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Tots and Toddlers</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <article id="prime"><h2>Welcome to Parties by Carol</h2>
    <p>
      For your next celebration, contact Parties by Carol. Whether your event is for two or two hundred, Parties by Carol can and will accommodate your needs. We specialize in fulfilling your every wish, whether at our facility or a location of your choice. We have a wide and varied menu that can be customized for your special event. Parties by Carol offers a combination of skills to help create unique and memorable occasions for you and your guests. So relax and leave everything to Parties by Carol. We aim to please and we will.</p>
  </article>
  <aside id="sbar1">
    <p>Beautiful Venue</p>
    <p>Devine Food</p>
    <p>Great Music</p>
    <p>Fun People</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </aside>
  <footer>&copy;Copyright - 2014 CAS</footer>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var MenuBar1 = new Spry.Widget.MenuBar("MenuBar1", {imgDown:"SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarDownHover.gif", imgRight:"SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarRightHover.gif"});
</script>
</body>
</html>



#prime h2 {
     margin-top:0; 
}

#prime p  {
         margin-bottom:0;
}

#prime h2, p  {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the margins be set the other way round? I'm guessing the `<p>` is below the `<h2>`.

```
h2 {
     margin-BOTTOM: 0; 
}

p  {
     margin-TOP: 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not working. I'm wondering if it's not working because h2 and p are inside article.??  Thanks for responding.